# how to make an input readonly when it has value?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm starting with aura and apex.
I've an aura component with a form.
Some inputs receive the values with data from an API. Those inputs, after receiving the value, should change to readonly. I need some help!!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that, in `disabled` you can add not empty/null conditions -

```html
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="msg" type="String" default="" />
    
    <lightning:input type="text" 
                     value="{! v.msg}"
                     label="Message" 
                     name="Msg"  
                     disabled="{! v.msg != ''}"/>

    
</aura:component>
```

Comment: step by step, we almost got it.    thanks. <>

now a new problem, when I put 1 character it's blocked, because != ' '

Comment: This is core idea. You can use onblur event, and in controller you can make one attribute to true. So that you'll get to type all the data. Also, if this answer solves the problem, you can select as Accept answer